# Is there a method of disabling a button in ReactJS after a certain number of clicks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm relatively new to React and I was working on a button that duplicates a component I created when clicked, but I want to limit the user to only be allowed to click on said button a set number of times (say 4 times) before the button is non-functional/removed. Here's a code snippet if it helps; is this possible? I thought about having a counter, but how would I implement that alongside the button?

Many thanks!

```
function App() {
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([]);

  const onAddBtnClick = event => {
    setInputList(inputList.concat(<Autocomplete items={foods} />));
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="foodcompleter">
        <Button onClick={onAddBtnClick} variant="primary" size="lg" block>Add Food</Button> 
        {inputList}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can basically check if `inputList.length === 4`, then you disable the button

Answer (score 0):

You can create your component CustomButton with a state that saves the number of clicks and after each state change just validate if the number of clicks is equal to your desired value.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the event listener after the click

```
const onKeyDown = (event) => { console.log(event) }

useEffect(() => {
window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown)

return () => { window.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown) }
}, [])
```